# Laravel Spatie/Media Generate Conversion with PHP on-the-fly

Tags: laravel

I am developing a project where I am importing literally hundreds of thousands of photos from a  legacy app. I have the seeding scripts all written and a nice CustomPathGenerator to deal with storing and retrieving that many images (a flat directory just won’t work for that many files). To speed up import and cut down on disk space usage, I want to disable the conversions during import and then re-enable them after. I have two questions. First, is there a method to disable auto-conversion when you add media to a model? Something like:

```
$myModel->addMedia($path)
     ->preservingOriginal()
     //->skipConversion() // don't do the conversion
     ->toMediaCollection('images');
```

Second, I would like to be able to generate conversions on the fly, similar to this:

```
$image = $myModel->getFirstMedia('images');
if( !$image->hasGeneratedConversion('thumb') ) {
 // $image->generateConversion('thumb'); // generate conversion on-the-fly
}
```

Is this built into the Media class, or will I have to build my own generateConversion method using the Spatie/Image package?

Using Spatie/Laravel-Media v8

Comment: can you try something like `$myModel->addMedia(...)->withConversions([])->...` see if that will set the conversions to nothing

Comment: The `addMedia()->withConversions()` method does not exist in v8. Thx

Comment: I would like to add, the first question is not as high a priority, since I can always comment out the conversion definition in my model class if needed. But I would definitely like to know if there is a built-in method to generate a conversion on-the-fly.